# Rails - Serialize collection with additional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use 'active_model_serializers' as serialization engine. By now my index method returns array of orders. `render json: @orders, each_serializer: Web::OrderSerializer`. Now I want to add additional field next to array. It's orders quantity. As a result, I want something like:

```
{
  "order_quantity": 12,
  "orders": [(serialized collection here)]
}
```

How should I code that using Active Model Serializers syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can use #map here to get serialized value of each order.

```
render json: { 
  orders: @orders.map{|order| Web::OrderSerializer.new(order).attributes},
  order_quantity: @orders.count // 12
}
```